# No funciona el formulario de Login en Symfony 6

Tags: symfony

Hice la autenticación en symfony 6 mediante éstos comandos, make:user, make:auth, meke:registration-form.
Eso genera todo lo que debe ser generado para que funcione la autenticación, !!En Teroría!!. Ahora bien cuando creo un usuario nuevo symony lo autentica de forma automática. El problema está cuando utilizo el formulario de Login que no hace nada, no autentica ni tampoco muestra un mensaje de error. Si alguien tiene la solución por favor de ayudarme, llevo varios días intentándolo y no tengo resultados.

Este el el código de la entidad Usiario que genera el comanmdo make:user

```
 <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['username'], message: 'There is already an account with this username')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    private $username;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

Ahora bien el comanando make:auth genera un controlador llamado SecurityController que tiene el siguente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

además crea el LoginFormAuthenticator que tiene el sigueinet código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('username', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_prueba'));
        /*throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);*/
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Estos dos comandos modifican el security.yml quedando de ésta manera:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

También se genera un formulario de login que es el sigueinte:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form method="post">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if app.user %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            You are logged in as {{ app.user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{ last_username }}" name="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" required>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >

    {#
        Uncomment this section and add a remember_me option below your firewall to activate remember me functionality.
        See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    #}

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

El problema es que no autentica. Cuando creo el usuario todo ok, pero cuando cargo el login que pongo usuario y contraseña no hace nada!!!.

Comment: Hola, deberías darnos más detalles, ejemplo de lo que has intentado... revisa [ask] y haz el [tour]

Comment: Vale, me explico mejor para que me puedan ayudar

Comment: @RaidelLasalleBatista a mi me ha sucedido lo mismo al actualizar de Symfony 5.4.7 a 5.4.8. Simplemente me redirecciona al login sin mensaje de error. La autenticación es similar, no usé make porque implementé la autenticación manualmente desde que tenía la aplicación en la versión 2.8, y he ido ajustando y funcionaba hasta que actualicé a la última mencionada.

Comment: No se si compartir mi código acá o abrir una nueva pregunta que sería redundante. realmente el log de SF no dice mucho sobre lo que pudiera estar sucediendo, algún problema con el componente de seguridad o incompatibilidad.

Comment: Me sucede exactamente lo mismo, habéis hallado la solución o habéis descubierto el problema?

Answer (score 0):

me ocurre lo mismo que a ti, encontraste la solución? mi versión de Sympony es 5.0.2, yo lo resolví editando el security.yaml de esta forma.

mi versión de Sympony es 5.0.2

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 4

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    proveedor:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            provider: proveedor
            
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta. yo he solucionado editando el archivo Segurity.yaml de esta  manera:

Answer (score 0):

Como les había comentado me ocurrió lo mismo al migrar de SF 5.4.7 a la versión 5.4.8
El mecanismo de autneticación de Symfony ha ido evolucionando, en el archivo `security.yaml` deben establecer el **entry_point** de tu aplicación: Además de que da la posibilidad de establecer cuantos **custom_authenticators** sean necesarios, quedando el mismo de la siguiente forma (las partes interesantes ok):

```
#security.yaml:
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            custom_authenticators: 
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\AuthenticationEntryPoint
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            form_login:
                login_path: usuario_login
                use_forward: true
                check_path: usuario_login
```

La implementación de `LoginFormAuthenticator.php`:

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{

    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'usuario_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): RedirectResponse
    {
        // add a custom flash message and redirect to the login page
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('security', 'You have to login in order to access this page.');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('usuario_login'));
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('_username', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        return new Passport(
                new UserBadge($username),
                new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('_password', '')),
                [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
                ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "You are now signed in. Greetings, commander.");

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Override to change what happens after a bad username/password is submitted.
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): Response
    {
        if ($request->hasSession()) {
            $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
        }

        $url = $this->getLoginUrl($request);

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route') && $request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
    }

}
```

La función `onAuthenticationSuccess`, tiene algo interesante: chequea que al autenticarse satisfactoriamente el usuario se verifica si en la session existe almacenada alguna ruta, y se redirecciona a la misma, en caso contrario se redirecciona al la ruta homepage de la aplicación. Por supuesto si usted lo desea puede eliminar o modificar este comportamiento dentro del evento.

Y he aquí la clase `AuthenticatorEntryPoint.php`, encargada de lanzar la excepción con código 401 en caso de autenticación fallida. Esta garantiza que en caso de perderse la session de usuario y al realizarse una petición AJAX se envíe un objeto response con código 401 (de esta manera se maneja adecuadamente del lado del cliente dándole un tratamiento especial al código de estado 401 en el error del ajax), y si no es AJAX la petición se redireccione al formulario login.

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'usuario_login';

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new Response("Acceso denegado!!!", 401);
        }

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('security', 'Debe autenticarse.');
        
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE));
    }

}
```

y la clase `AccessDeniedHandler.php`, básicamente traduce una excepcion de tipo AccessDeniedException del framework, a un objeto responde con el mismo mensaje de la excepcion y el mismo código de estado (401 ha de ser).
namespace App\Security;

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{

    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException): ?Response
    {
        return new Response($accessDeniedException->getMessage(), $accessDeniedException->getCode());
    }

}
```